# How to Populate Treeview node.checked to true or false by getting nodes.text and set to true or false

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have treeview named treeview1 with few child nodes in form1 and each nodes have a checkbox. I got the checked node and saved in database checked value as true and unchecked as false in a table. i need to modify checked value to true or false by populating them in a another treeview named treeview2 in form2

My treeview look somewhat like this

[image]

Form this i have to modify those checked values in another TreeView2 which is in form2. Here i need to Get Node name and set True or False from database and populate in Treeview2 Node checked.

Note: I have saved Checked Node in Database Checked as True and Unchecked as False. From this i have to modify it again by populating in treeView2 which is in Form2. i need only method to check Node.Text and set checked from db.

Here is the code that collect all nodes name in a list

```
 private IEnumerable<TreeNode> ModifyGetUNNodes(string NodeName, bool nodeVale)
    {
        var checkUnNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
        GetUnNodes(checkUnNodes, ModifyTreeView.Nodes, NodeName, nodeVale);
        return checkUnNodes;
    }

    // Return a list of the TreeNodes that are checked.
    private static void GetNodes(ICollection<TreeNode> checkedNodes, IEnumerable nodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            checkedNodes.Add(node);

            // Check the node's descendants.
            GetNodes(checkedNodes, node.Nodes);
        }
    }
```

from above code i got all names of node. Here i need to check the Name and set checked data true or false

```
        var allNodes = ModifyGetNodes();
        var allNodeList = allNodes.Select(node => node.Text).ToList();
```

form this check node Text

```
 if(node.Text == "Bread")
     node.checked = y.Bread
```

here y.Bread as value true.

```
if(node.Text =="Chips")
      node.checked =y.Chips
```

here y.Chips as Value false.

Some what like this i have to check name and set checked value in treeview2 in form2
[image]

When i load Form2 i have to get node checked, by getting the data form database

> Note: I saved the Node Bread Checked as true in Column Bread as(true) and Wine which is Unchecked so it will save in Column Wine as(False).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*.

Comment: Can you explain *i need to modify checked value to true or false by populating them in a another treeview*, please?

Comment: @OlivierRogier I have 2 forms with same treeview, i saved the form1 treeview checked nodes as true and unchecked as false in a table. I have to populate checked node in treeview2 in form 2 to do modification, mean well i can again check few more nodes or uncheck and save it again in datatable.

Comment: I don't understand your problem: if you know how to save from the form1, you know how to save from form2, isn't it? I see you have an answer. If it does not suits, can you provide your actual code and screenshots please?

Comment: @OlivierRogier  I Save those checked Value form form1 treeview1 in DB, but thing is i have populate in form2 treeview2 as if treeview1 as checked and Unchecked which save to db in corresponding names as true and false. when open form2 i have to get data from Database.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand *i have populate in form2 treeview2 as if treeview1 as checked and Unchecked which save to db in corresponding names as true and false. when open form2 i have to get data from Database*. English is not my natural language and Google Translate does not help me more to understand. I need code and screenshot to try to help you in case I can.

Comment: Ok. All your question is unclear for me. I don't understand your vars and methods namings, and many things are missing like what is `y`. You want to open a form2 having a listview containing only the nodes from listview in form1 having state to checked changed depending of some names?

Comment: @OlivierRogier  Thank for your Time and effort, i found the answer, on my above code i just modified passed two more args with node.text and db column values. so now i load form two am getting the result i need. But am keeping this Question Open to get some new answer.

Comment: Great! Have a good job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I got Answer

```
    private IEnumerable<TreeNode> ModifyGetUNNodes(string NodeName, bool nodeVale)
        {
            var checkUnNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
            GetUnNodes(checkUnNodes, ModifyTreeView.Nodes, NodeName, nodeVale);
            return checkUnNodes;
        }

        // Return a list of the TreeNodes that are checked.
        private static void GetNodes(ICollection<TreeNode> checkedNodes, IEnumerable nodes, string nodeName, bool checkValue)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                if(node.Text == nodeName)
                   node.Checked = checkValue;

                // Check the node's descendants.
                GetNodes(checkedNodes, node.Nodes);
            }
        }
```

In this code i just passed two more args and checked the Node.text and set it as checked and UnChecked form the Data Column Values.

Now i call The Function with passing **args** name of node and checked value

Example :

```
    var getData = DbContext.tblMenu.Select(x => x).ToList();
   foreach(var y in getData)
    {
     ModifyGetUNNodes("Bread", y.Bread.value);
    }
```

Here the y.Bread is column name which holds the checked value(True or False).